# How do I bind an ObservableCollection to a ComboBox?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox, observablecollection, vb.net-2010

How do I get even basic binding to work between a `ComboBox` and an `ObservableCollection`? I can't get anything but error messages.

VB:

```
Class MainWindow
    Dim Units As New ObservableCollection(Of String)

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
        Units.Clear()
        Units.Add("in")
        Units.Add("mm")
        Units.Add("cm")
    End Sub
End Class
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Height="59" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="136,96,0,0" Name="ComboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="319"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Units}"/>
</Grid>
```

No matter what I do, the `ComboBox` always seems to be empty and there's an error message in the console:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Units' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindow' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Units; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='ComboBox1'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the XAML, change to just {Binding}, or equivalently, {Binding Path=.}:

```
<ComboBox Height="59" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="136,96,0,0" Name="ComboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="319" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

Set the Data Context explicitly to the object, from code behind, in the *Window_Loaded* event handler:

```
ComboBox1.DataContext = Units;
```

Comment: I've done exactly what you suggested and I'm still getting the same error message and the ComboBox is still empty. Argh.

Comment: Hooray, it works! Thank you! ...now, if only I understood the difference between this and the dozens of variations I tried, heh.

Comment: @evilspoons Yeah, it's different than C# too, which is why I got tripped up.  Apparently in VB you have to set the DataContext explicitly on the XAML element you're binding (setting on its parent doesn't work).